# bash script to extract ALL matches of a regex pattern

Tags: bash, shell

I found this but it assumes the words are space separated.

```
result="abcdefADDNAME25abcdefgHELLOabcdefgADDNAME25abcdefgHELLOabcdefg"

for word in $result
do
    if echo $word | grep -qi '(ADDNAME\d\d.*HELLO)'
    then
        match="$match $word"
    fi
done
```

POST EDITED

Re-naming for clarity:

```
data="abcdefADDNAME25abcdefgHELLOabcdefgADDNAME25abcdefgHELLOabcdefg"
for word in $data
do
    if echo $word | grep -qi '(ADDNAME\d\d.*HELLO)'
    then
        match="$match $word"
    fi
done
echo $match
```

*Original left so comments asking about `result` continue to make sense.*

Comment: I'm having trouble making sense of your script. Is `$world` supposed to correspond to `$result`? There's nothing in your pattern that will match anything in `$world` however. Can you show a better example of the string you're trying to match and the pattern you're trying to use?

Comment: I edited the post, it was incorrectly stated.

Comment: It's still not clear what result you're looking for. Now `for word in $result` only sees one "word" (the full string contained in `$result`. What do you want `$match` to contain at the end?

Comment: I want to extract all occurences of the regex pattern inside the var "result". The var "match" should contain all the extracted matches each separated by a space.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Edit: answer to edited question:**

```sh
for string in "$(echo $result | grep -Po "ADDNAME[0-9]{2}.*?HELLO")"; do
  match="${match:+$match }$string"
done
```

**Original answer:**

If you're using Bash version 3.2 or higher, you can use its regex matching.

```sh
string="string to search 99 with 88 some 42 numbers"
pattern="[0-9]{2}"
for word in $string; do
  [[ $word =~ $pattern ]]
  if [[ ${BASH_REMATCH[0]} ]]; then
    match="${match:+$match }${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
  fi
done
```

The result will be "99 88 42".

Comment: I edited my post: My string does not have spaces, therefore it will not work.

Comment: why not shorten it a bit: ... do; [[ $word =~ $pattern ]] && match="${match:+match }${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"; done

Comment: @user377178: It's a matter of style choice and readability. Choose what works best for a particular circumstance.

Comment: Why the parameter substitution with the variable "match"? I don't understand the purpose of it.

Comment: @Akito: There's a space at the end of the parameter substitution. The result is that a space is added to the value of `match` between each value.

Answer (score 18):

Use `grep -o`

> -o, --only-matching       show only the part of a line matching PATTERN

Comment: 7 years later this was exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant - and there are problems because of greedy matching - but this more or less works:

```
data="abcdefADDNAME25abcdefgHELLOabcdefgADDNAME25abcdefgHELLOabcdefg"
for word in $data \
    "ADDNAME25abcdefgHELLOabcdefgADDNAME25abcdefgHELLOabcdefg" \
    "ADDNAME25abcdefgHELLOabcdefgADDNAME25abcdefgHELLO"
do
    echo $word
done |
sed -e '/ADDNAME[0-9][0-9][a-z]*HELLO/{
        s/\(ADDNAME[0-9][0-9][a-z]*HELLO\)/ \1 /g
        }' |
while read line
do
    set -- $line
    for arg in "$@"
    do echo $arg
    done
done |
grep "ADDNAME[0-9][0-9][a-z]*HELLO"
```

The first loop echoes three lines of data - you'd probably replace that with `cat` or I/O redirection.  The `sed` script uses a modified regex to put spaces around the patterns.  The last loop breaks up the 'space separated words' into one 'word' per line.  The final `grep` selects the lines you want.

The regex is modified with `[a-z]*` in place of the original `.*` because the pattern matching is greedy.  If the data between ADDNAME and HELLO is unconstrained, then you need  to think about using non-greedy regexes, which are available in Perl and probably Python and other modern scripting languages:

```
#!/bin/perl -w
while (<>)
{
    while (/(ADDNAME\d\d.*?HELLO)/g)
    {
        print "$1\n";
    }
}
```

This is a good demonstration of using the right too for the job.